# Google Groups Migration API gives 503 "Backend Error"

Tags: http-status-code-503, google-groups-api, google-groups-migration

Getting the below 503 response from the Group Migration API's Insert method (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/groups-migration/v1/reference/archive/insert).

I'm just trying to work through a spike with the example payloads - though if I fiddle with the POST, I can get the 401 or 404 errors; cannot create the 400 error. Is anybody else using this API successfully?  Are there temporal service issues with the service?

Thanks!
Chris

REQUEST:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/groups/v1/groups/testmaspa@googlegroups.com/archive?    uploadType=media HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: message/rfc822
Authorization: Bearer blah...
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 470
Expect: 100-continue

Received: by 10.143.160.15 with HTTP; Mon, 16 Jul 2007 10:12:26 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID: NNNN@mail.samplegroup.com
Date: Mon, 16 Jul 2007 10:12:26 -0700
From: "chris@mnaspa.org"
To: "chris@mnaspa.org"
Subject: TEST SUBJECT
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline
Delivered-To: testmaspa@googlegroups.com
This is the body of the migrated email message.  Booyah!
```

RESPONSE:

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Dec 3 2012 11:16:02 (1354562162)
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 08 Dec 2012 00:36:53 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 177

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
```

Comment: I'm having no issues with my code hitting the API. Can you post a code sample?

Answer (score 2):

503 is overquota, typically...and it is happening a lot recently...might be due to some of the additions to the Group Settings API?  We increased our quota and still received 500 errors.

We have a ticket in and it has been acknowledged as a problem and it is being investigated.  Some stability has returned but it is still a large problem for us.

Our daily quota limit request has not been increased yet, but maybe those requests are reviewed weekly.

Best regards,
  David

Answer (score 0):

you should change Message-ID from NNNN@mail.samplegroup.com to <NNNN@mail.samplegroup.com>

Please see also [Google Groups Migration C# API Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709495/google-groups-migration-c-sharp-api-not-working/21574683#21574683).