# Google Groups Migration C# API Not Working

Tags: c#, api, google-apps, google-email-migration, google-groups-migration

I'm trying to use the C# Google Groups Migration API and not having much luck.

I have the following code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var body =
    @"Received: by 10.143.160.15 with HTTP; Mon, 16 Jul 2007 10:12:26 -0700 (PDT)
    Message-ID: NNNN@mail.samplegroup.com
    Date: Mon, 16 Jul 2007 10:12:26 -0700
    From: ""xxx""
    To: ""xxx""
    Subject: SUBJECT
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    Content-Disposition: inline
    Delivered-To: xxx
    This is the body of the migrated email message.";

    var bytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);

    var messageStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

    var auth = new OAuth2LeggedAuthenticator("xxx.com", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
    var service = new GroupsmigrationService(auth);
    service.Key = "xxx";

    var request = service.Archive.Insert("xxx", messageStream, "message/rfc822");
    request.Upload();
}
```

...but this results in an `Invalid Credentials` exception.

I also tried the following:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var body =
            @"Received: by 10.143.160.15 with HTTP; Mon, 16 Jul 2007 10:12:26 -0700 (PDT)
            Message-ID: NNNN@mail.samplegroup.com
            Date: Mon, 16 Jul 2007 10:12:26 -0700
            From: ""xxx""
            To: ""xxx""
            Subject: SUBJECT
            MIME-Version: 1.0
            Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed
            Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
            Content-Disposition: inline
            Delivered-To: xxx
            This is the body of the migrated email message.";

        var bytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);

        var messageStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

        // Register the authenticator.
        var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
        provider.ClientIdentifier = "xxx";
        provider.ClientSecret = "xxx";
        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);

        // Create the service.
        var service = new GroupsmigrationService(auth);

        service.Key = "xxx";
        var request = service.Archive.Insert("xxx", messageStream, "message/rfc822");
        request.Upload();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
    {
        // Get the auth URL:
        // IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { TasksService.Scopes.Tasks.GetStringValue() });
        IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.migration" });

        state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
        Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

        // Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
        Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
        Console.Write("  Authorization Code: ");
        string authCode = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
        return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
    }
}
```

...but that fails with: `Backend Error`. The inner exception is:

> The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

Ideally I'd prefer the to use the 2 Legged Authenticator approach as it doesn't require manual intervention in copying and pasting an auth-key, but right now getting anything to work would be a plus.

Any help gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

503 error usually indicated that you are hitting the API quota

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/groups-migration/v1/limits

Would you wait a 24 hours period and try to re-run again?  The quota resets itself on a daily basics.

Additionally, you should tag your migration related question with google-email-migration and for group migration with google-groups-migration

Comment: Emily: We have only ever ran this a handful of times and still get the same result. I tried it just now having not ran it for days and got the following exception: 

System.Exception was unhandled
  Message=Backend Error
  Source=Google.Apis

The inner exception is:

Message=The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

...this is using OAuth2.

Using 2Legged I get invalid credentials, even though I'm using the same technique and credientals I use to successfully read data from other Google APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, and asked to google's support team.

In result, we found that this problem reproduce because "Message-ID" header in example has invalid format.

This typo has been fixed at [August 12, 2013.](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-migration/v1/limits)

Please try to change Message-ID from NNNN@mail.samplegroup.com to <NNNN@mail.samplegroup.com>.